# How this field can be updated using a DropDownList inside the GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: 
---------------
Username, Name, JobTitle, BadgeNo, IsActive, DivisionCode 


Divisions Table:    
----------------
SapCode, DivisionShortcut
```

And I have a GridView that I am using it to add, delete and update/edit the employees information. This information is employee Username, Name, BadgeNo, JobTitle, IsActive (from Employee table) and the DivisionShortcut (from Divsions table). The Divisions will be listed in DropDownList. The divisions will be listed as a DropDownList inside the GridView and it will be shown in the Edit mode. I am struggling now with updating the division of the employee through this DropDownList. I wrote the code but I got the following error:
*

> Invalid column name 'DivisionShortcut'.

- **ASP.NET Code:**

  ```
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <%# Eval("DivisionShortcut")%>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:DropDownList ID="DivisionsList" runat="server" DataSourceID="DivisionsListDataSource"
                                          DataTextField="DivisionShortcut" DataValueField="SapCode"></asp:DropDownList>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Network ID" ReadOnly="True" 
                  SortExpression="Username" />

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <%# Eval("Name")%>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeeName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Name")%>' />
                  </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Title">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <%# Eval("JobTitle")%>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtJobTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobTitle")%>' />
                  </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Badge No.">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <%# Eval("BadgeNo")%>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtBadgeNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BadgeNo")%>' />
                  </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Is Active?">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <%# Eval("IsActive")%>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  <EditItemTemplate>
                      <asp:CheckBox ID="isActive" runat="server" 
                                    Checked='<%# Eval("IsActive").ToString().Equals("True") %>'/>
                  </EditItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete?">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <span onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete the record?')">
                          <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkB" runat="Server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                      </span>
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
          ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UsersInfoDBConnectionString %>" 

          SelectCommand="SELECT     dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.employee.Username, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.employee.JobTitle, dbo.employee.BadgeNo, dbo.employee.IsActive
                          FROM         dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN
                                      dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode"
          UpdateCommand="UPDATE [employee], [Divisions] SET [Name] = @Name, [JobTitle] = @JobTitle, 
                                              [BadgeNo] = @BadgeNo, [DivisionShortcut] = @division WHERE [Username] = @Username"
          DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [employee] WHERE [Username] = @Username">
          <UpdateParameters>
              <asp:Parameter Name="Name" Type="String"  />
              <asp:Parameter Name="JobTitle" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="BadgeNo" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="DivisionShortcut" Type="String" />
              <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
          </UpdateParameters>
          <DeleteParameters>
              <asp:Parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
          </DeleteParameters>
      </asp:SqlDataSource>
  ```

I forgot to mention that there is a SqlDataSource for the DropDownList.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DivisionsListDataSource" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:UsersInfoDBConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Divisions">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
    //For editing any row in the GridView
        protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) 
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        }

    //For updating the information in any row in the GridView
        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow gvrow = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            DropDownList DivisionsList = (DropDownList)gvrow.FindControl("DivisionsList"); 

            TextBox txtEmployeeName = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("txtEmployeeName");
            TextBox txtJobTitle = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("txtJobTitle");
            TextBox txtBadgeNo = (TextBox)gvrow.FindControl("txtBadgeNo");

            CheckBox isActive = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("isActive");

            //For getting the ID (primary key) of that row
            string username = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

            string name = txtEmployeeName.Text;
            string jobTitle = txtJobTitle.Text;
            string badgeNo = txtBadgeNo.Text;
            string division = DivisionsList.SelectedValue.ToString();

            UpdateEmployeeInfo(username, name, jobTitle, badgeNo, division);
        }
private void UpdateEmployeeInfo(string username, string name, string jobTitle, string badgeNo, string division)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersInfoDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string update = @"UPDATE Employee SET Name = @Name, JobTitle = @JobTitle, 
                                                BadgeNo = @BadgeNo, DivisionShortcut = @division
                            WHERE Username = @Username";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", jobTitle);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BadgeNo", badgeNo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@division", division);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", isActive.checked);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            //            SqlDataSource1.UpdateCommand = @"UPDATE Employee SET Name = @Name, JobTitle = @JobTitle, 
            //                                                BadgeNo = @BadgeNo 
            //                                                WHERE Username = @Username";
            //            SqlDataSource1.Update();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

So how am I going to be able to update the Division of the employee through the DropDownList?

UPDATE:

I updated the UpdateEmployeeInfo() method but still I am getting the same error.

Updated Code:

```
private void UpdateEmployeeInfo(string username, string name, string jobTitle, string badgeNo, string division)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersInfoDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string update = @"UPDATE Employee SET Name = @Name, JobTitle = @JobTitle, 
                            BadgeNo = @BadgeNo WHERE Username = @Username; 
                            UPDATE Divisions SET [DivisionShortcut] = @division WHERE SapCode = @SapCode;";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(update, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobTitle", jobTitle);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BadgeNo", badgeNo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@division", division);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", isActive.checked);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am Seeing is you are using **UpdateEmployeeInfo** methode to update Employee table's column  as well as Division Table's column, but in that sql query , you mentioned only employee table, That is why you are getting this error because  **DivisionShortcut** is not a part of employee table.

According to my understanding you should use **DivisionCode** in place of **DivisionShortcut**
and Make the AutoPostBack="True" for your dropdown list

Comment: Could you please help me with it? Because I tried to modify my code as shown in the updated question but still is not working.

Comment: @TechLover According to my understanding you should use DivisionCode in place of DivisionShortcut

Comment: @TechLover keep the code like that it will work you have to make AutoPostBack="True" for your dropdown list or else it's not going to take the selected value. Try with this and let me know

Comment: No, it did not work. I am still facing problem with the @SapCode.